# VideoView: закрытие Activity после окончания проигрывания файла

Tags: android, videoview, java

Народ, подскажите, пожалуйста, как закрыть Activity по окончании проигрывания. Вот мой код:

```
final VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoViewPresentation);

video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);

myVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
myVideoView.requestFocus(0);

t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myVideoView.start();
    }
});

t.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо слушать листенер окончания проигрывания и там убивать активити.

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener()
```

Comment: Спасибо все получилось.